# Type of capacitor for crystal resonator

Tags: capacitor, crystal

The Atmega328p datasheet recommends the following circuit to work with its internal crystal resonator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0XI9z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I can't find any recommendations on the type of capacitors to use.  I think the reasonable options are mica and thin film. *Maybe* also ceramic NP0 (emphasis on the NP0 type), which is a lot less expensive.

Any advice?  I tend to believe that either type is ok, mica and thin film probably being the absolutely safe bet?  Again, any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Ceramic NP0 will be fine. I don't have a good source, though, so I'm leaving this as a comment.

Comment: I would just use NPO (C0G)

Comment: Those are typically smd ceramic capacitors.  Don't know what type (NP0 or what) or if it matters.

Answer (score 6):

One might choose an X7R cap if was essential for profitability to shave a penny in small sizes or for gen. purpose use but in important applications where accuracy and quality is important, **always choose NP0/COG 1%** if the value is <1000 pF.  ( low k density)

So choosing an NP0/COG is wisest for several reasons. (low-microphonics, zero temp error (<50ppm) and stable accuracy with V, aging etc.)  But if your tolerance is high , you can use the internal RC oscillator.

For ceramic caps with stable temperature curves, **N250** is -250 ppm/'C while  **P150** is +150ppm/'C  and **NP0** is 0 ppm +/-50ppm/'C  ( aka COG)

---

The value is twice the rated crystal load capacitance (in series becomes half) minus stray load proximity to ground plane and input capacitance (e.g. 2*C + 2~3pF = CL )

But the other answers are also correct, in a benign environment, any cap will help it oscillate.

AT cut Crystals have a 3rd order temperature curve that are cut for different tolerances and temperature,T,  ranges to control the peak frequency f(T) swings which crossover at room temp.   So the value of these caps shifts to Xtal curve at 25'C temp to the precise frequency specified for rated load within the specified ppm tolerance.  (25~100ppm)

Parallal Cap Xtals are always specified by f, Tolerance/ Stability/ aging and temp range.  e.g. XTAL, 10.000 MHz 50/50/5 ppm, -40 ~ +70'C  xxyy case

While Tuning fork resonators have a 2nd order (parabolic) temperature curve centered at room temp. so a cap. selection cannot compensate for this in a TCXO, only a varicap diode with a custom correction curve.

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince75 It seems that your answer responds to my answer (about TCXO); shouldn’t you rephrase it to make it independant? Moreover, you seem to imply that the OP should either use NP0/COG capacitors or use the internal RC oscillator. But isn’t a crystal oscillator with non-NP0/COG capacitors much more accurate and stable than an RC oscillator? Anyway, your answer is very interesting, I upvoted it.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you need absolute frequency stability, any capacitor should be just fine.

The crystal’s own temperature coefficient may affect the frequency more than the capacitor’s temperature coefficient.

If you need absolute frequency stability, you need to find capacitors whose temperature coefficient will compensate the crystal’s (that’s a TCXO) or make a circuit whose temperature is controlled (that’s an OCXO).

Answer (score 1):

Worked with a gal who designed crystal oscillator circuits for MCUs.
She called me into the lab one day because "My amplitude at 40MHz is so high we are afraid the crystal will be overheated and break. Can you figure out why the VoltPP is so high?"

After a couple hours of lab observation and listening, and couple days of musing as worked on other tasks, I realized the ESD structures were consuming so much energy, at 40MHz, the stable amplitude was indeed higher than simulated.

The ESD losses needed to be in the simulation. Only recently, 10 years later, is that company learning to characterize their IOpads/circuits with Network Analyzers.

Summary: the capacitor losses matter. There is no difference between PCB capacitors and onchip ESD-diode-junction-capacitance. ESR matters.

Comment: ESL of  tracks can also cause huge resonance at this frequency.  NPO/COG have lower ESR for ceramic caps. Also need FET buffered Diff Probes to avoid measurement error.